# Can I prevent it from being line when mapping GPS to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, gps, thingworx

Good morning? I am SeonHo.

The intent of my question is clear.
Does Thingworx has function that prevent some of the GPS values from being received and displayed as a straight line, or does it has function that show the non-straight route?

I will explain more.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5MzN.png)

When you look at the pictures, you can see that some of the routes are straight.
This is because the GPS value is not received at a certain time or period, or the module is turned off.
When you receive the GPS value again or when the module is turned on, the GPS value is clearly different.
So I think it is displayed in a straight line.
I wonder if it has the ability to show the path between two GPS points that are represented by this straight line.
Please introduce

[picture that i want make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKNUu.png)

The important thing is to make straight path the normal route  between two GPS points.
It is important to make the path of the red straight line in the picture look like purple.
Is it possible?
Or any suggestions to me?
Help
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Location data can be inaccurate, and to force the points to lie on the road, you will need to use a snap-to-roads API

- [Google Maps snap to roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)
- [OSRM match service](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#match-service)

If you are looking for an end-to-end solution that visualises location data on the road, you can also try the HyperTrack SDK for Android or iOS (not the same as an IoT solution). Location data from automotive drives is automatically snapped to roads. (Disclaimer: I work at HyperTrack.)